# How to pass a bundle of a LinkedHashMap FROM Fragment back to its Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an expandable listview in an activity containing questions in groups. My answers are answered in a fragment when user choose the question.

I gather the positions of child and group positions in a LinkedHashMap.

How to send this Map back to the Activity?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simplest way is to pass it to Activity by simple setter:

inside Activity:

```
private LinkedHashMap linkedHashMap;
public void setLinkedHashMap(LinkedHashMap linkedHashMap) {
this.linkedHashMap = linkedHashMap;
```

}

inside some method in fragment:

```
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
myActivity.setLinkedHashMap(linkedHashMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare an interface.

```
interface ActivityListener {
    onGroupPositionsReady(LinkedHashMap map);
}
```

You implement it in your Activity.
And then implement the following in the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Object host = getHost();
    if (host instanceof ActivityListener ) {
        activityListener = (ActivityListener ) host;
    }
}
```

And when you are ready with the map.

```
activityListener.onGroupPositionsReady(yourMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Through an interface.

Define a custom interface, for example:

```
public interface BackToActivity {
    void onAnswersChosen(LinkedHashMap map);
}
```

Your activity must implement it. Then, from fragment, call `((BackToActivity)getContext).onAnswersChosen(map)`